# Regex to filter certain type of url

Tags: php, regex, url, web-crawler

I am writing and learning a simple crawler script to read all links within a website. I have a problem with the pattern, and I do not understand why this is not working.

The links looks like this in the sourcecode of the website:

```
<a  href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/154567062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Holz%22">Handlauf Holz  </a>
```

My pattern and function looks like this:

```
preg_match_all( '/ObjectPath.*"/', $contentrow, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER
```

It works for the first half, but after that it breaks the output. Here a sample of the output where its broken:

ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Categories">-**GESAMTANGEBOT**-Handläufe

ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS01%22/SubProducts/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS%2001%20014%22&#ProductRatings"

ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Categories/CustomerInformation"

ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS01%22/SubProducts/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS%2001%20014%22&ChangeAction=SelectSubProduct" method="post"

The part in the sourcecode, where the part was get from, looks like this:

```
<a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/345456456/Categories">-GESAMTANGEBOT-</a><a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/1234346q/Categories/Handlauf">Handläufe</a><a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%22">Handläufe Edelstahl</a>
```

I do not understand, why the part -GESAMTANGEBOT- is taken into the pattern. the " should finish it?

Thank you!

Here the complete Script:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function getPage($url){      

  // Prüfung ob cURL installiert ist?   
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){             
    die('Curl not initialed');       
  }

  // Array mit den cURL-Einstellungen
  $options = array(        
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,      
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",        

      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10 
  );

  $ch      = curl_init( $url );    
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );     

  $content = curl_exec( $ch );    
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );    
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );    
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );    

  curl_close( $ch );     

  $header['errno']   = $err;    
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;    
  $header['content'] = $content;    

  return $header;
}


$url = "http:/domain.com/epages/23455467.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS01%22/SubProducts/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%20DS%2001%20014%22";
$domain = 'http://www.domain.com/epages/452563456.sf/de_DE/?';

$content = getPage($url);
$i=0;
foreach ($content as $contentrow) {
    //go through content and look for links
    if (preg_match_all( '/ObjectPath(.*)"/', $contentrow, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER )) {
        $i++;
        echo '<h1>'.$i.'</h1>';
        foreach ($output as $row) {
            $url= $domain.$row[0];
            //echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
            echo $url;
            echo '<br /><h2>onerow</h2><br />';
        }
    }
}

//print_r($content);
```

And I forgot to mention, I receive this warning above the output:

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\readratings.php on line 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have something like:

```
<a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/345456456/Categories">-GESAMTANGEBOT-</a><a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/1234346q/Categories/Handlauf">Handläufe</a><a class="BreadcrumbItem" href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%22">Handläufe Edelstahl</a>
```

And you want all those parts:

```
ObjectPath=/Shops/345456456/Categories
ObjectPath=/Shops/1234346q/Categories/Handlauf
ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Edelstahl%22
```

While I don't know why you have this strange output, you should be able to get what you want with a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) operator. This should do what you want:

```
/ObjectPath(.*?)"/
```

as it will stop at the first ".
In this case, it's equivalent to:

```
/ObjectPath([^"]*)"/
```

though it's not in a general case.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Works fine! the strange output is from a shopcms which really is not worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$contentrow = '<a  href="?ObjectPath=/Shops/154567062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Holz%22">Handlauf Holz  </a>';
preg_match_all( '/ObjectPath(.*)"/', $contentrow, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($output);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ObjectPath=/Shops/154567062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Holz%22"
            [1] => =/Shops/154567062/Categories/Handlauf/%22Handlauf%20Holz%22
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But unfortunatedly this does not solve the problem. I added the whole script. It starts with an url and should ouput me all internal links at the website. With your correction the output is still the same